# Add a button in a new column to all rows in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, row

I have a `DataGridView` object:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = an.peaks;
```

(an.peaks is a `List<Point>` object. `Point` type has 3 properties: x,y,z)

witch generates the next table on run-time: (Apparently I cant upload an `Image` yet because I'm a new user so I'll try to draw it :)

```
____|_x__|_y__|_z__|[new column ]
____|_11_|_12_|_13_|[text/button] <==\
____|_20_|_30_|_40_|[text/button] <== } Add text if something or button if something else.
____|_50_|_60_|_70_|[text/button] <==/
```

I would like to add buttons (as shown in the image/drawing) in a new column to each row that satisfying some condition. If the condition is not satisfied add some text instead.

Example: If the point already exist in the database show it's substance name (each point represent a substance). If not add a button "ADD" to the corresponding row that will add the new point to the database.

The conditions are not the problems - they are only for examples. The problem is adding the buttons/text to each row and the clicking event for the new button/s.

Comment: Take a look at [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually quite simple to do using the `DataGridView`. What you need to do is:

#### Add column of type DataGridViewButtonColumn

[`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx) is a standard `DataGridView` column type. It can be added through the designer but I generally prefer using code (usually in the form constructor).

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True;
col.Text = "ADD";
col.Name = "MyButton";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Setting `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` true means that the `Text` property gets applied to all buttons giving them the "ADD" button text. You can also use `DataPropertyName` to point at a column in the grid's datasource to provide the button text, or you can even set each cell's value directly.

#### Change buttons to text

Once you have your button column you then want to turn particular buttons to text. You do this by replacing a cell of button type with one of text type. You can do this many places but one of the best is in the `DataBindingComplete` event handler - this event fires once the grid is bound and ready to display but before it is painted.

Below I simply grab the row with index 1 but you can also inspect each rows `Value` property.

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["MyButton"] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
}
```

#### Respond to button clicks

The final part of the problem is responding to button clicks. This is a little bit cludgy - you need to either use the `CellClick` event or the `EditingControlShowing` event for the entire grid.

- CellClick

  ```
  private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,
      System.Windows.FormsDataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
  { 
      if (DataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MyButton") 
      { 
          // button clicked - do some logic
      } 
  }
  ```
- EditingControlShowing

  ```
  void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
       DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Control is Button)
      {
          Button btn = e.Control as Button;
          btn.Click -= new EventHandler(btn_Click);
          btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
      }
  }

  void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int col = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
      int row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
      // Rest of the logic goes here!
  }
  ```

In your case the editing control approach is probably best since it won't respond to clicking on buttons that have been replaced with text. Also this way is more like how you respond to any other button on a form.

Comment: I wish I had read that earlier (I didn't get an email that the question was answered - must change settings...).
Anyway I had used a different approach by using ListBox. Although less "Professional", somewhat more "Aesthetic". Maybe I'll go back and switch if I'll Have the time. Thanks.

Comment: @Igor if you find this answer or Unril's at all useful, give them an upvote.

Comment: Tried that...I can't! :))) I'm 1 point short for being able to vote-up :D

Comment: @Igor, oh well :) Mainly just happy that you found yourself something that works.

Comment: Weather you hit your head against the wall until it breaks (the wall, yes?!) or you find a bypass. I choose the second because of the time limitations ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [WPF host control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx) to WinForms project and use DataGrid with [CellTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609837%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For example:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:FieldModifier="private">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:PointDataTemplateSelector x:Key="pointDataTemplateSelector" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate">
      <Button Click="OnAddButtonClick" Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">Add</Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="textTemplate">
      <TextBlock>Exists</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource pointDataTemplateSelector}"></DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And selector class:

```
public class PointDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null && item != null && item is Point) {
            var point = (Point)item;

            // Logic here.
            if (point.X >= 5) {
                return element.FindResource("buttonTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            return element.FindResource("textTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It may by easier than WinForms way.

Comment: WPF host control in Windows Forms is good pattern ? performance issues ?